# Is it possible to control node position in 2D ? ( graphviz )

Tags: graphviz, rank

[image]Is it possible to set rank attirbute in both direction?

I know that it is possible to set in one direction.
But I want to set both direction.

For example, the next code will generate attached graph.
But I want to control vertical position of "d" node.

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    a -> b -> c
    b -> d
    { rank=same b d }
}
```

I tried source code position like "d" first,
but it did not affect its vertical position.

Answer (score 1):

Graphviz does not allow two directional ranking.  However, the **group** attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) usually (but not always) accomplishes your goal.  Note that **group** requires edges connecting all the nodes in the group.  Also **group** is applied to nodes, while **rank** is applied to subgroups.

In this case, the **group** attribute did not produce the desired result until other changes were made.
The graph below has TB **rankdir** and associated changes to **rank=same** plus the use of **group**

```
digraph G {
    //rankdir=LR

    c [group=G]
    d [group=G]
    { rank=same a -> b -> c}
    b -> d 
    c -> d [style=invis]
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: Sroush, thank you for your comment and information about graphviz.  It was worth for me to know that graphviz can not rank two directions at the same time, and that group might be able to affect some position.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some time I can found workaround for this case.
Thank you Sroush.

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR

    a -> b -> c
    up
    down
    {rank=same; b up down }

    up -> b [dir=back]
    b -> down [style=invis]
    down      [style=invis]

}
```

[image: work around using one dummy node]